# ListenableScheduledFuture and ListeningScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, guava, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am creating an instance of ListeningScheduledExecutorService via following code

```
service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize));
```

as described in [guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningScheduledExecutorService.html).

but when i call

```
Future future = service.schedule(callableObj, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

variable "future" is of type "ScheduledFuture" and not of type "ListenableScheduledTask".

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of [`schedule`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) is [`ListenableScheduledFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableScheduledFuture.html):

```
ListenableScheduledFuture<MyObj> lsf = 
    service.schedule(callableObj, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: changing the type to "ListenableScheduledFuture" gives compilation error as follows 
/Users/gaurav/Documents/workspace/portal-bheem-fe/src/com/bsb/portal/event/AbstractEventListener.java:39: error: incompatible types
    [javac]             ListenableScheduledFuture<Object> future = executorService.schedule(obj, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    [javac]                                                                                ^
    [javac]   required: ListenableScheduledFuture<Object>
    [javac]   found:    ScheduledFuture<Object>

Comment: Update your Guava version :)